# Successfull pushing to the Github but not changing

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I pushed to my GitHub from a usual repository, but it`s not working and there is no change and commit on my repo page on GitHub!
Also, I tried to clone it first and try to push it again, unfortunately, there is no change on its GitHub page!
Last night this repo was working correctly and I`m sure everything is OK in this repo!

Comment: If you’re pushing from a console window, is there an error message?

Comment: No, it wrote:

```git push eastcloud mEnumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 297 bytes | 297.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), completed with 2 local objects.
ter
To https://github.com/miladxandi/Simplist```

Comment: Seems github server is not accessible right now. https://status.github.com/messages

Comment: No there is a successful message with a correct target repo address!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems github server is not accessible right now. https://status.github.com/messages